# SSRS (VS 2013): How can I have a row group that spans multiple columns?

Tags: ssrs-2012

[image]

Hi guys, I'm trying to create a report similar to the picture shown. I need to be able to group by Risk Category and display the line 'Risk events for Risk Category  X' for each risk category either above or below column headings.

I have spent a few hours playing with row groups but I've unable to display the group header spanning across the columns.

Is this even possible with SSRS? Any ideas on how to do this will be much appreciated.

thanks
Cam.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is put the header label in the first column you want it to be seen under, then use the [merge cells function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220511.aspx) to bridge it across however many columns you need.